# Visual Studio Build output list of failed projects

Tags: visual-studio, build, output-window

I was debugging a big .sln in Visual Studio 2022.
In the output window it shows the message:

========== Build: 16 succeeded, 6 failed, 13 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========

I was wondering if it is possible to get a short summarized list, which projects could be built successfully and which failed?

Answer (score 1):

- There is a visual studio extension called [Visual Studio Build Timer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OdysseasPetrocheilos.VisualStudioBuildTimer)

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But does extension work for Visual Studio 22? The description of the extensions says "works with Visual Studio 2019,2017 and 2015"?

Comment: @Pascal You could try [MSBuild built-in summary tool](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-4-detailed-build-summary/)